# Searching within the result of a vlookup using a range of values and parsing text

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

**MY GOAL:**

parse a MM/DD date from the result of a vlookup so that it can be used in a project plan

**BACKGROUND:**

- The vlookup result contains multiple values separated by a "•" (I don't need all of them)
- The value I'm looking to parse is not always in the same location in the vlookup result (otherwise I could use the RIGHT formula)
- There is a finite number of the values I'm looking to retrieve (and I know them already)
- The value that I'm looking to retrieve contains some text with a date range; I only want the first four values in the date range (MM/DD)
- I'd like to achieve all this with a single formula with the result in a single cell

**CURRENT FORMULA**

- The formula that I've been working on that is not working is:

  `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(iserror(search(Iterations!D2:D7,(VLOOKUP(A2,'Results {2596503}'!$C$2:$L$183,3)))),,))`

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p4NcpDYqh6fJQJbe2ijd-Y5vCSe8iefbHtvjH7SL50M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I took a look, but your comments are not clear: "I would like to part "08/17" for the start date but not have col b and just nest the formlus in col c" -and- "I would like to part "08/28" for the end date but not have col b and just nest the formlus in col c." I recommend that you just show the results you want rather than trying to explain them. Also, your sheet is "View Only." Please set the share permission to "Anyone with the link can edit." Otherwise, you will miss out on quality solutions, as many volunteers here bypass sheets that do not offer edit access.

Comment: In addition, you'll want to give realistic entries for Column B, since parsing out the date portions will require knowing which symbols may ever appear in non-date parts of the Column-B entries (e.g., will there be hyphens elsewhere? forward slashes elsewhere?).

Comment: Thanks Erik. I updated the results I want in col c and d and also changed the sharing settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set up a sheet called "Erik Help" with the following formulas in B2 ad C2:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",MID(VLOOKUP(A2:A,data!A2:B,2,FALSE),FIND(REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(A2:A,data!A2:B,2,FALSE),"[0-9]-[0-9]"),VLOOKUP(A2:A,data!A2:B,2,FALSE))-4,5)))
```

and

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",MID(VLOOKUP(A2:A,data!A2:B,2,FALSE),FIND(REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(A2:A,data!A2:B,2,FALSE),"[0-9]-[0-9]"),VLOOKUP(A2:A,data!A2:B,2,FALSE))+2,5)))
```

respectively.

They may be longer than actually needed, but you did not share realistic results in Column B or list which symbols may appear in Column B other than in the date; so I tried to account for either a hyphen or a forward slash possibly appearing in Column B in places other than within the date span.

Your analytics sheet also shows a formula that is sorting the results from data!A:A. So even though in your example the original data order happens to be the same as in analytics!A:A, that is not a given (again, based on your formula). Therefore, the VLOOKUP is also necessary.

You did not indicate whether you need to further *use* these returned date-snippets in calculations, or whether you just need to *view* them. So the results generated in "Erik Help" are text.

If you want usable numbers/dates, you add further issues that would need to be controlled for in the formula, because you'll only be extracting month and day, not year. That's fine right now. But what about when the date range to be extracted is "12/28-01/13"? If you simply make these values/dates, they will *both* be assigned to the current year. So the end date here will wind up being earlier than the start date.

Because of this, I've added a second sheet, "Erik Help 2," which contains extended formulas to account for these cases while still returning the date format you want as actual dates which can be used in calculations.

Comment: Thanks, Erik. Could you explain why you wrote the regex like "[0-9]-[0-9]"? Specifically, what is the middle hyphen doing?

Comment: Your embedded date ranges are all of the type "xx/xx-xx/xx" (e.g., "09/28-10/22"). So it appears they will all share a number-hyphen-number pattern in the middle (in the example I just gave, that would be "8-1"). I chose this identifier because you did not share whether hyphens might appear elsewhere in your text blocks in Column B. The likelihood of a number-hyphen-number pattern showing up elsewhere in the blocks, however, seemed small. So the formula locates this pattern, then backs up X characters or moves forward X characters to find the start of each date.

Comment: If the solution(s) I've provided correctly address the issue raised in your original post, please take the time to mark my answer as "Best Answer." It helps other experts know that a case is resolved as well as helping future searchers easily find answers to their own similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT
*(following your note on the sheet: "I would like to remove col b altogether and nest in the formulas in col c and d")*

You can adjust the range `B2:B` by replacing it with your already existing formula in `B2`.

The new adjusted formula will become

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(ARRAYFORMULA(sort(unique(data!A2:A))),data!$A$1:$C,2),"\d+\/\d+-\d+\/\d+"),"-")))
```

---

**Original answer**

You can use the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"\d{2}\/\d{2}-\d{2}\/\d{2}"),"-")))
```

Make sure you **format the results as `Date`**.
*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFNA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IFNA(TEXT(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(
 VLOOKUP(data!A2:A, data!A:C, 2), "\d+/\d+-\d+/\d+"), "-"), "mm/dd"))))
```

[image]